# Rselenium org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException

Tags: web-scraping, rvest, rselenium, selenium-remotedriver

Using RSelenium, I want to click the

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVfm3.png)
 button. this page has two views a desktop mode and a mobile mode, 
I think the desktop view is hidden and does not allow you to click. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPbxH.png).

```
server <- phantomjs(port=5005L)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port=5005L)
remDr$open()    
remDr$navigate("https://catalogo.movistar.com.pe/samsung-galaxy-note-10-plus")
    remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE) 
    element<- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "body > div:nth-child(6) > div.container.detail-view > div.detail-main-head-container > div.detail-main-right > div.phone-details-specs > div.phone-specs > div.phone-specs-planes > div > div > div.owl-stage-outer > div > div:nth-child(4)")
    element$clickElement()
    remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

Apparently I must show the hidden view to be able to click because in mobile mode I do not get it.

Your help please. Aquí le tome una foto a mi pantalla con las salidas de la ejecución del código [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqYrM.png)